# object reference not set to an instance of an object upon creating a new Android project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I get this when I want to create a new Android project.

[image: object reference not set to an instance of an object]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `Android Studio` is not installed on your computer. If it is, uninstall it and run the Visual Studio installer again until all `Android SDK` errors go away.

Make sure Visual Studio is closed and install the most recent stable version of Xamarin for Visual Studio . I found it here: https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads. (Trying to install it through VS didn't work for me under Tools -> Android -> Settings -> Xamarin for Visual Studio Updates.)

Make sure you have `Java SDK` version 7 installed on your machine. You also must use the 32-bit version even if you have a 64-bit machine. This was key!

Install the `Android SDK`. **Standalone version**, not Android Studio + Android SDK.

Install the `Android NDK`.

Restart your computer and open **Visual Studio**. Go to Tools -> Android -> Settings and set the correct paths to `Android SDK`, `NDK` and `Java SDK`.

You should be good to go with creating a new project.

Comment: You absolutely do *NOT* have to uninstall Android Studio... In fact you can use Android Studio to update the Android SDK, just point both IDEs at the some Android SDK location. Also the latest Android SDK version (and Xamarin's tools) work fine w/ Java 64-bit.